# How to solve the knapsack Problem when more than two properties of the Item are given (3 variables)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

In the knapsack Problem how to solve it if one more property other than that of weight and value of the Item is given? Like recently I was asked a question where I was given 3 properties of the same items, Weight, Value and Type:

```cpp
int weights[5] = {1, 3, 5, 9, 10};
int values[5] = {11, 13, 1, 19, 9};
int types[5] = {1,2,1,3,4};
int capacity = 26;
```

We can choose items of each type only once, e.g. we can have only one item of type = 1 in our final knapsack, so we either choose the item with weight 1 or the item with weight 5 both cannot be present. We have to maximize the profit we get.

I was thinking along the lines of a 3D matrix, but I'm not able to think of the proper solution, if I couldn't even think of the base case in this situation for the types, how would the recursive solution look like in this case?

Here is what I tried, I choose each element, the type of the element is put in a set, then we recurse. If the next item type is already present in the set, then we remove it and then recalculate the max value for that particular type among all of them, but if the item type is not present in the set, then we have not considered it, and we add it to the set and proceed further.

I also have a lingering doubt about the base case. Since we can have a different item of the same type which gives a more profit, in my base case, if the value for that particular item type is already considered, then it will return the same output without maximizing it for the second item of the same type. But then I countered myself that the `n` and `w` values are different for the same type so it will in fact maximize this too. Is this correct?

Related Questions that I found but weren't answered or Did not have a Pseudo code on which I could build upon:

- [Solving the knapsack problem with special constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73885794/solving-the-knapsack-problem-with-special-constraint)
- [How can I solve knapsack problems with 3 variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639862/how-can-i-solve-knapsack-problems-with-3-variables)

After reading the second link, I'm also curious on how we could apply the constraint of the Volume, how would the code actually look like with the base cases?

I was also suggested to use a map of `(string, int)` values to store the unique values from the recursion, which method would be better? to use a map or to use 3D table?

Here is my code:

```cpp
set<int> ttypes;
int static t2[6][26][5];
int knapSack_Memo_Modified(int weights[], int values[], int types[], int w, int n){
    if(w <= 0 || n <= 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(t2[n][w][types[n-1]] != -1){
        return t2[n][w][types[n-1]];
    }

    if(ttypes.count(types[n-1])){
        ttypes.erase(types[n-1]);
        return t2[n][w][types[n-1]] = max(t2[n][w][types[n-1]], knapSack_Memo_Modified(weights, values, types, w, n-1));
    }
    else{
        ttypes.insert(types[n-1]);
        if(weights[n-1] <= w){
            return t2[n][w][types[n-1]] = max((values[n-1]+knapSack_Memo_Modified(weights, values, types, w-weights[n-1], n-1)), (knapSack_Memo_Modified(weights, values, types, w, n-1)));
        }
        else if(weights[n-1] > w){
            return t2[n][w][types[n-1]] = knapSack_Memo_Modified(weights, values, types, w, n-1);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int weights[5] = {1, 3, 5, 9, 10};
    int values[5] = {11, 13, 1, 19, 9};
    int types[5] = {1,2,1,3,4};
    int capacity = 25;

    memset(t, -1, sizeof(t));
    int ans = knapSack_Memo_Modified(weights, values, types, capacity, 5);

    int mx = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
                mx = max(mx, t2[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << mx << endl;
}
```

Comment: Chances are this problem has already been studied. So the difficult part is finding the right keywords to describe the problem. "Multiple constraint knapsack problem" is not it, and will redirect you to problems where two variables act like the weight (imagine having to fill a sack for the most value, but you want both the total weight to stay under some threshold and the total volume to stay under some threshold). I think "knapsack problem with conflict" can be what you're looking for.

Comment: For instance ["conflict knapsack problem" on google scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=conflict%20knapsack%20problem)

Comment: In your small example, note that there are only two items which have the same type. So you could branch: 1) Ignore the first item; Solve the knapsack problem with the other items only. 2) Ignore the second item; Solve the knapsack problem with the other items only. 3) Keep the best of the two solutions you found.

Comment: If the number of conflicts is small, you can repeat this strategy. But note that it is exponential in the number of disjoint conflicts. (For instance if items 1 and 2 conflict, and items 3 and 4 conflict, and items 5 and 6 conflict, then you need to solve 2x2x2 = 8 instances of the knapsack problem)

Comment: One way to rephrase this knapsack-with-conflict problem into a multidimensional-knapsack problem is to add one weight dimension per type of item, and items of that type have weight 1 in this dimension, and other items have weight 0 in that dimension, and the capacity in every dimension is 1.

Comment: A MIP (Mixed-Integer Programming) model may be easier.